# Login middleware Web y Auth Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

Quiero hacer un login para administradores, pero cuando me logueo, me vuelve al login.

En routeServiceProvider defini:

> ```
>  protected function mapAdminRoutes() {
>         Route::middleware('web')
>                 ->namespace($this->admin)
>                 ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
>     }
> ```

En routes/admin defini:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'prefijo'], function () {

    //GUEST
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function() {
        Route::group(['namespace' => 'Login'], function() {
            Route::get('login', [
                'uses' => 'LoginController@showLoginForm',
                'as' => 'login'
            ]);

            Route::post('login', [
                'uses' => 'LoginController@authenticateAdmin',
                'as' => 'FinDraT.login'
            ]);
        });
    });

    //AUTH
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::group(['namespace' => 'Home'], function() {
            Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
        });
    });
});
```

Y en mi controlador tengo:

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

public function authenticateAdmin(Request $r) {
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $r->input('email'), 'password' => $r->input('password')])) {
        if (Auth::user()->hasRoleAdmin('SYSADMIN') || Auth::user()->hasRoleAdmin('admin')) {
            return redirect()->intended('prefijo/home');
        }
        return redirect()->route('home');
    } else {
        return back()->with('error-credentials', 'Email y/o contrasena incorrectos.')
                        ->withInput();
    }
}

public function showLoginForm() {
    return view('admin.login.index');
}
```

}

Las rutas del admin tienen en el RouteServices provider el middleware web. Y despues yo defino tambien el middleware Auth. Esto no puede ser un problema?

Comment: Cuando envías el formulario de login, ¿al menos logras llegar a `authenticateAdmin`? No veo ningún problema en usar web y auth por aparte, es correcto.

Comment: Sinceramente no se que paso que ahora anda. En un rato sigo programando y si vuelve a fallar comento aca! Gracais @Shaz

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque según los comentarios del OP al parecer nunca hubo un error por resolver.

Answer (score 2):

No sé para que quieres hacer dos inicios de sesión, especulo que dependiendo del tipo de usuario mostrarás más o menos módulos del sistema según corresponda. Si es así, te recomiendo utilizar el mismo inicio de sesión y crear *middlewares* para permisos de usuario:

En la consola ejecuta:

```
php artisan make:middleware IsAdmin
```

En la migración de *users* agrega:

```
$table->tinyInteger('profile');
```

En el modelo de *user* agrega a `$fillables`, *profile* y también una constante:

```
public static $_ADMIN = 1;
```

... y también la siguiente función:

```
public function isAdmin(){
    return $this->profile === self::$_ADMIN;
}
```

El *middleware* creado déjalo de la siguiente manera:

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class IsAdmin
{
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$this->auth->user()->isAdmin()) {
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Luego regístralo en el *kernel*:

```
'is_admin'=> \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
```

Por último, puedes llamar al *middleware* dentro de la función `construct` de cada controlador y darle permiso solo a los métodos que necesitas, por ejemplo:

```
$this->middleware('id_admin, ['only'=>['create','store']]);
```

o bien utilizarle en el *Route*:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['is_admin']], function() {

});
```

Comment: No es lo que busco, pero gracias por compartir!